# In Python, does 'return self' return a copy of the object or a pointer?

Tags: python, class, pointers

Let's say I have a class

```
class A:
    def method(self):
        return self
```

If `method` is called, is a pointer to the `A`-object going to be returned, or a copy of the object?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It returns a reference:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> id(a)
40190600L
>>> id(a.method())
40190600L
>>> a is a.method()
True
```

You can think of it this way: You actually *pass* `self` to the `.method()` function as an argument and it returns the same `self`.

Answer (score 7):

It returns a reference to the object, look at the following example:

```
class A:
    def method(self):
        return self

a = A()
print id(a.method())
print id(a)
> 36098936
> 36098936

b = a.method()
print id(b)
> 36098936
```

About the `id` function (from [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id)):

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer (or long
>   integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object
>   during its lifetime.