# Purpose of return self python

Tags: python, return

I have a problem with `return self`

```
class Fib: 
    def __init__(self, max):
        self.max = max
    def __iter__(self): 
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 1
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        fib = self.a
        if fib > self.max:
            raise StopIteration
        self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a + self.b
        return fib
```

I have already seen this question [return self problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37320751/in-python-does-return-self-return-a-copy-of-the-object-or-a-pointer) but I can't understand what the benefit is of `return self`?

Comment: Define benefit?

Comment: [`__iter__` in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__). You can start reading there. Short answer: `__iter__` returns `self` because it's needed for an iterator.

Comment: @Elliot RobertsWhat is the use of ?

Comment: `return self` would return the object that the method was called from.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Returning `self` from a method simply means that your method returns a reference to the instance object on which it was called. This can sometimes be seen in use with object oriented APIs that are designed as a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) that encourages [method cascading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_cascading). So, for example,

```
>>> class Counter(object):
...     def __init__(self, start=1):
...         self.val = start
...     def increment(self):
...         self.val += 1
...         return self
...     def decrement(self):
...         self.val -= 1
...         return self
...
>>> c = Counter()
```

Now we can use method cascading:

```
>>> c.increment().increment().decrement()
<__main__.Counter object at 0x1020c1390>
```

Notice, the last call to `decrement()` returned `<__main__.Counter object at 0x1020c1390>`, which *is* `self`.
Now:

```
>>> c.val
2
>>>
```

Notice, you cannot do this if you did not return `self`:

```
>>> class Counter(object):
...     def __init__(self, start=1):
...         self.val = start
...     def increment(self):
...         self.val += 1
...         # implicitely return `None`
...     def decrement(self):
...         self.val -= 1
...         # implicitely return `None`
...
>>> c = Counter()
>>> c.increment().increment()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'increment'
>>> c
<__main__.Counter object at 0x1020c15f8>
>>> c.val
2
>>>
```

Notice, not everyone is a fan of "method cascading" design. Python built-ins do not tend do this, so, `list` for example:

```
>>> x = list()
>>> x.append(1).append(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
>>>
```

The one place you *do* often see this is when your class implements the `iterator` protocol, where `iter` on an iterator returns `self` by convention, although this is suggested by [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators):

> Having seen the mechanics behind the iterator protocol, it is easy to
>   add iterator behavior to your classes. Define an `__iter__()` method
>   which returns an object with a `__next__()` method. If the class
>   defines `__next__()`, then `__iter__()` can just return `self`:
>
> ```
> class Reverse:
>     """Iterator for looping over a sequence backwards."""
>     def __init__(self, data):
>         self.data = data
>         self.index = len(data)
>
>     def __iter__(self):
>         return self
>
>     def __next__(self):
>         if self.index == 0:
>             raise StopIteration
>         self.index = self.index - 1
>         return self.data[self.index]
> ```

Notice, this in effect makes your iterator only useful for a single pass (as it **should** be to properly follow the iterator protocol):

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> it = iter(x)
>>> list(it)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list(it)
[]
>>> next(it)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>>
```

Comment: @AmrElgendy you're welcome. I have added one more bit of information at the end, so check out the latest edit.

Comment: I'd imagine it's possible to modify the code and make your iterator reusable. Reset `index` to `len(data)` just before you raise StopIteration.

Comment: @Timir you probably wouldn't want to do that though, then it would become an infinite iterator. In general, iterators *should not be re-usable*.

Comment: Are we talking about method cascading or method chaining ? Apparently, in the wikipedia link you sent, these two things are different.

Comment: @MarineGalantin I think there is some ambiguity, from the link, "Cascading can be implemented in terms of chaining by having the methods return the target object (receiver, this, self)." although some might only consider it cascading if you support a particular kind of sugar.

Answer (score 1):

This is needlessly complex code. Pay little attention to it. There's no reason on earth to implement it this way.

That being said, what it does is this:

```
class Fib: 

    """Implements the Fibonacci sequence."""

    def __init__(self, max_):
        self.max = max_

    def __iter__(self):
        """Initializes and returns itself as an iterable."""

        self.a = 0
        self.b = 1
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        """What gets run on each execution of that iterable."""

        fib = self.a
        if fib > self.max:
            raise StopIteration
        self.a, self.b = self.b, self.a + self.b  # increment
        return fib
```

This is all much easier to express as:

```
def fib(max_):
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b <= max_:
        out = a
        a, b = b, a+b
        yield out
```

Examples:

```
>>> fib_obj = Fib(20)
>>> for n in fib_obj:
...     print(n)

>>> for n in Fib(20):
...     print(n)

>>> for n in fib(20):
...     print(n)
# all give....
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
```

Comment: Is that mean `self.a = 0
        self.b = 1` Will be implemented for one time ??

Comment: @AmrElgendy `__iter__` is run once to initialize an iterator (that is, an object with a `__next__` method) and `self.a` and `self.b` are used in that `__next__` method. It's a silly way to implement the object.

Comment: sorry , this is last question
What I understand is `__iter__` implement for one time when calling it from `__next__`  that's right ??

Comment: @AmrElgendy no, but you're digging way deeper into the language than you probably need to be. If you're interested, read the official docs.