# Is chained method (method cascading) encouraged or discouraged by pep?

Tags: python, pep

inspired by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43380360/11074017), I am assuming that PEP8 is discouraging chained method (method cascading).

built-ins are the proof.

```
>>> x = list()
>>> x.append(1).append(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

but i didn't find related doc by search on [pep](https://www.python.org/)

any idea?

Comment: This won't work anyway because `append` doesn't return anything. It just modifies the list in-place

Comment: You mean PEP 8?

Comment: (and the only list method i'm aware of that can be chained is `.copy()` but it doesn't even chain on the original list but a copy of it)

Comment: The post you linked to doesn't say what you claim. It doesn't even mention PEP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PEP 8 leaves serval things up to you to decide how best to layout your code. The key theme throughout is that your code should be clear and readable.
The example you provide doesn’t work as .append returns nothing.

Here is an example with strings:

```
x = "This"
x = x.strip().replace("T","t")
print (x)
```

Which might be easier to read in the following layout:

```
x = "This"
x = (x
     .strip()
     .replace("T","t")
     )
print (x)
```