# create chain methods for class in python

Tags: python

Let's say I have the following class:

```
class MyClass: 
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def strip(self):
        strip_text = self.text.strip()

        return strip_text

    def reverse(self):
        rev_text = self.text.strip()[::-1]

        return rev_text

my_name = MyClass('todd ')
```

I want to able to to call the methods to this class like this:

```
my_name.strip().reverse()
```

However, when I do so, it throws an error.  How do I go about chaining methods?

Comment: you need to return self so be able to chain operations, so instead of returning strip_text, set self.strip_text = strip_text and return self

Comment: This is called a *fluent interface*. Not as common in Python, although some third-party libraries use it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43380042/purpose-of-return-self-python/43380360#43380360)

Comment: _it throws an error_ Seeing the error would help a lot in tracking down the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Purpose of return self python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43380042/purpose-of-return-self-python)

Comment: `my_name.strip()` returns an ordinary string, which does not have a `.reverse()` method.

Comment: When you get to `reverse`, I think the error is because `my_name.strip()` becomes a `String`, not part of your `Class`

Answer (score 1):

`my_name.strip()` returns a `String`, which has no `reverse()` function.

A quick way is just to make `my_name.strip()` a new Class object, and reverse that:

```
MyClass(my_name.strip()).reverse()
```

<sub>(However, IMO this is kludgy and there's a better (more pythonic) way to fix this in the Class definition(s) itself.)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Each function has to replace the wrapped string, then return `self`. At the *end* of the chain, you retrieve the final result.

```
class MyClass: 
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def strip(self):
        self.text = self.text.strip()

        return self

    def reverse(self):
        self.text = self.text.strip()[::-1]

        return self


my_name.strip().reverse().text
```

As an alternative to mutating the existing object, a new instance can be returned at each step.

```
class MyClass: 
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def strip(self):
        return MyClass(self.text.strip())

    def reverse(self):
        return MyClass(self.text.strip()[::-1])
```