# Call a method n times by appending it to itself in a python object

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Say i have a python class `Sum()` with a method `add()` that can take a list of numbers for manipulation, say

```
sum = Sum()
sum.add([5, 8, 2])
```

I want to instead call the `.add` method on each list item by 'appending' to itself. How can i achieve this?

`sum.add(5).add(8).add(2)`

For clarity, i have seen the two implementations in [keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification_with_hub#:%7E:text=the%20full%20model%3A-,model,-%3D%20tf.keras.Sequential)

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
   hub_layer,
   tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
   tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])
```

*Which can also be represented as*

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(hub_layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
```

I want to achieve the second for the above scenarios, whereby I call the `.add` method `n` times for each item I have in a list

Comment: You can do `sum.add(5).add(8).add(2)` only if the method `add(self, num)` returns the self object instead of returning `null`.

Answer (score 1):

in your add function, simply return object itself

```py
def add(self, number: int):
    # do your stuff
    return self
```

this works because the next .add is going to be executed on the returned element of the previous .add (aka the object itself)

hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks. I needed to include the `return self`

Answer (score 0):

For being able to chain methods, you need the method to return the instance of the object (aka `self`). You can find some additional information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43380042/purpose-of-return-self-python).

If you object `sum` has a method `add`, then you can write `sum.add(x)`. However, you can't call `add` on anything, you can only call it on instances of this class `Sum`. So if you want to do `sum.add(x).add(y)`, you need that `sum.add(x)` is an instance of `Sum`, so the `add` method should return a `Sum` instance. If you want the object itself to be modified (and not create another one), you need `add` to return `self`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the `add()` method returning a `Sum` object for this to occur.

Here is a minimal example. (I named the class `A` because `sum` is a Python function and it is better not to confuse the two. )

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, n=0):
        self.value = n
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)
        
    def add(self, a_list):
        self.value += sum(a_list)
        return self


x = A()
print(x)

x.add([3, 3])
print(x)

x.add([10,10]).add([1,1,1])
print(x)
```

Output:

```
0
6
29
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the method `add` on `Sum` objects. Let's decompose the line

```py
sum.add(5).add(8)
```

`add(5)` is applied to the `Sum` object `sum`.

`add(8)` must be applied to a `Sum` object as well, so `sum.add(5)` must return a `Sum` object as well.

In general the `add` method must return a `Sum` object